# ios - WACloudAcessToken undeclared

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, azure

When i'm trying to get token from azure,i'm getting an error like "WACloudAcessToken" undeclared in the following code.

```
WACloudAccessToken* accessToken;

accessToken = [[WACloudAccessToken alloc] initWithDictionary:pairs];  

[WACloudAccessControlClient setToken:accessToken];
```

Can anyone give the proper solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following notes. if you missed correct it.

1. WACloudAcessToken.h are imported correcly or not?
2. WACloudAcessToken.m is correcly added in compiler sources.
3. If this file from any static library check other linker flags from build settings.